# Accurate Reflection of Size of Sum of Large Numbers with Integer Arithmetic

Tags: python, numpy, integer-overflow

Thanks again for your time. I hope I didn't bug you guys too much.
When the sums overflows, but the mean is within range, how to get an accurate idea of the size of sum fast with integer arithmetic?

Mean wond't overflow, but it is not integer arithmetic. Natural log works in mathematics, but is slow in programming.

```
>>> k = numpy.empty((10), dtype=numpy.int64)
>>> k[:] = 9223372036854775807
>>> print k
[9223372036854775807 9223372036854775807 9223372036854775807
 9223372036854775807 9223372036854775807 9223372036854775807
 9223372036854775807 9223372036854775807 9223372036854775807
 9223372036854775807]
>>> numpy.sum(k)
-10
>>> numpy.mean(k)
9.2233720368547758e+18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
numpy.iinfo(numpy.int64).max
```

gives

```
9223372036854775807L
```

So, you are getting an overflow when integer values are used as in summation. But, on the other hand

```
numpy.finfo(numpy.float64).max
```

gives

```
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

So, you don't get an overflow while computing the mean since the computation of mean uses floating values and the result is correct. It overflows if you use values larger than the permitted maximum.

Comment: Thank you for answering my original question.

Comment: Since I didn't ask the question I wanted to ask clearly, I have just edited it. I would vote up if i have 15 reputation.